# add a NEW value in a list

Tags: vex

I have a problem with this VEX script.
`@` create attributes instead of variables.

```
f[]@myList; // create list attribut
float pavW = 0.0;
for( int i = 1 ; i < 11 ; i++){
    string path = "../widthPav" + itoa(i);
    pavW = ch(path); // take the value in the specific channel
    if (i == 1){
        push(@myList,pavW); //add new component of value to myList
    }
    if ( pavW > 0){
        foreach ( int j ; float value ; @myList){
            if ( pavW == value){
                break;
            }else{
                push(@myList,pavW); //add new component...
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

I want to add  `pavW` value to `myList` if `pavW` is different than the elements of `myList`. The result is not as expected.

Comment: it's a vex script , a proprietary langage of a 3d software. it looks like C.
@ allows you to create attributes , it's like variables but you can use them in the 3d context

Comment: Just because it looks like C doesn't mean it should be tagged C. Anyway, now that a new tag is created, if you could kindly link to a reference manual so the tag description could be populated, it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

In `foreach` you are comparing to the first element of `array` only. And for other elements your `if` conditions fails and keeps on adding to the `myList`. You should `push` to the `array` outside `foreach` block.

A temporary var named `unique` can be used to trigger the `push`.

```
f[]@myList; // create list attribut
float pavW = 0.0;
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
    string path = "widthPav" + itoa(i);
    pavW = ch(path); // take the value in the specific channel
    if (i == 1)
    {
        push(@myList, pavW); //add new component of value to myList
    }
    if (pavW > 0)
    {
        int unique = 0;
        foreach (float value; @myList)
        {
            unique = 1;
            if (pavW == value)
            {
                unique = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (unique)
            push(@myList, pavW); //add new component...
    }
}
```

**Suggestions**:

- You don't need index in `foreach`.
- For this kind of task, simply create an spare parm and add a `Python`
  expression to get list of unique `widthPav` parm.

Simple `Python` snippet:

```
node = hou.pwd()
parmsUniqueValue = []

[parmsUniqueValue.append(parm.eval()) for parm in node.parms() if parm.name().startswith('widthPav') if parm.eval() not in parmsUniqueValue]
```